# Label text alignment in tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm having a bit of difficulty with the alignment of point labels in `tkz-euclide`. For (a simple) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=2,xmin=0,xmax=5]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){a}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){g}
\tkzDefPoint(3,1){k}
\tkzDefPoint(4,1){d}
\tkzDrawPoints(a,g,k,d)
\tkzDrawSegments(a,g g,k k,d)
\tkzLabelPoints[below=6pt](a,g,k,d)
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{document}​
```

gives me this (the red lines, added afterwards, illustrate):

[image: Showing misaligned labels]

Please suggest a way to fix this. I would much prefer something automatic, so I don't have to tune things like `[below=5.283pt]` by hand.

**Note:** I have assumed this is `tkz-euclide`, but this *may* be a `tikz` problem. Whatever -- I've tagged both. (And, of course, as usual, it turns out to be a problem between the keyboard and the chair.)

---

Building on Alain Matthes' answer, I've added these lines:

```
\tikzset{place above/.append style={anchor=base,yshift=6pt}}
\tikzset{place below/.append style={anchor=base,yshift=-12pt}}
...
\tkzLabelPoints[place above](a,g,k,d)
\tkzLabelPoints[place below](a,g,k,d)
```

(of course, the numbers may vary -- I'll relativise it later). The result:

[image: Showing corrected alignment]

Great package!!!

Comment: Try adding `anchor=base` to `\tkzLabelPoints` options.

Comment: @Luigi : Thank you. As you probably saw from Alain's answer, I also had to change `above/below` to `yshift`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exactly a problem with `tkz-euclide`. With this version of `tkz-euclide` you can use all the options of `tikz`.

The definition of `\tkzLabelPoints` is

```
\tikzset{label style/.style={\tkz@euc@pointpos,\tkz@euc@labelcolor,font=\normalsize}}
\def\tkzLabelPoint{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@LabelPoint}{\tkz@LabelPoint[]}} 
\def\tkz@LabelPoint[#1](#2)#3{\node[label style,#1] at (#2) {#3};}%

\def\tkzLabelPoints{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@LabelPoints}{%
                                         \tkz@LabelPoints[]}}% 
\def\tkz@LabelPoints[#1](#2){%
 \foreach \point in {#2}{
 \node[label style,#1] at (\point) {$\point$};}
}%
```

So you can modify `label style` or add your options in  `#1`( this is the argument of `\tkzLabelPoints`) and you can use both possibilities like below ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=2,xmin=0,xmax=5]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){a}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){g}
\tkzDefPoint(3,1){k}
\tkzDefPoint(4,1){d}
\tkzDrawPoints(a,g,k,d)
\tkzDrawSegments(a,g g,k k,d)
\tikzset{label style/.append style={anchor=base}}
\tkzLabelPoints[yshift=-16pt](a,g,k,d)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Alain, merci beaucoup pour votre réponse, et, aussi, pour `tkz-euclide`.